# glmer inverse Gaussian distribution and identity link, some models failed to converge

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm

I'm relatively new to GLMM and am experiencing some difficulty with model convergence. Specifically, I have a data set from 200+ participants, each of whom completed 200 trials of a visual search task. I'm trying to examine whether their RTs changed as functions of trials (from the 1st trial to the 200th trial, centered at the midpoint), two categorical variables (coded as -0.5/0.5), and their interactions.

I followed [Lo & Andrews' (2015)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.01171/full) recommendation to use a series of generalized liner mixed model with a inverse-Gaussian distribution and an identity link to account for the fact that RT data are positively skewed.

However, as I started building my models, the simplest model: `glm0<-glmer(RT~cent_trial+(1|subject),final.dat,family=inverse.gaussian(link="identity))`
gave me these two errors:

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.379158 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

Results from the simplest model:

```
 Family: inverse.gaussian  ( identity )
Formula: RT ~ cent_trial + (1 | subject)
   Data: final.dat

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 747885.4  747920.2 -373938.7  747877.4     45142 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1138 -0.6113 -0.2174  0.3410 29.8407 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 subject  (Intercept) 1.886e+05 4.343e+02
 Residual             6.591e-05 8.119e-03
Number of obs: 45146, groups:  subject, 240

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.851e+03  1.865e-04 20652053   <2e-16 ***
cent_trial  -4.726e+00  1.865e-04   -25344   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr)
cent_trial 0.000 
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.379158 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

Though, as I added more predictors to the model: `glm2<-glmer(RT~cent_trial+Feedback+Prevalence+(1|subject),final.dat,family=inverse.gaussian(link="identity"))` these error messages disappeared.

Results from the model above:

```
 Family: inverse.gaussian  ( identity )
Formula: RT ~ cent_trial + Feedback + Prevalence + (1 | subject)
   Data: final.dat

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 747880.2  747932.5 -373934.1  747868.2     45140 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1117 -0.6099 -0.2159  0.3418 29.6671 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 subject  (Intercept) 1.771e+05 4.208e+02
 Residual             6.603e-05 8.126e-03
Number of obs: 45146, groups:  subject, 240

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 3773.44197    3.86486  976.35   <2e-16 ***
cent_trial    -4.72718    0.06793  -69.59   <2e-16 ***
Feedback    -377.67642    4.37414  -86.34   <2e-16 ***
Prevalence   533.15690    4.68888  113.71   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) cnt_tr Fedbck
cent_trial -0.003              
Feedback   -0.128  0.001       
Prevalence -0.127  0.000 -0.094
```

I tried to add more iterations or use a different optimizer, but they did not seem to resolve this issue. I wonder what's causing it?

Comment: Hi @Mellowbook249, welcome to CV. The message says "Rescale variables?" - have you tried that? does this link help too? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164457/r-glmer-warnings-model-fails-to-converge-model-is-nearly-unidentifiable

Comment: Hi @Alex J, can you be more specific about which variable may need to be rescaled? My DV (RT) was measured in milliseconds, trials are from 1 to 200 (and have been centered to the midpoint, e.g., -99, -98, ... 99), and the other categorical variables are just coded as -0.5/0.5. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know because I can't see the data. However, if you look at the size of your parameter estimates in the output, they are massive. The suggestion of scaling and centering was applied to all variables in the top-rated answer in my link - from your description, probably it's the DV that needs to be rescaled.

Comment: Something else you might want to try: a different link function. Is there a particular reason you have chosen the identity link? Because the mean of an I.G. distribution is positive, but an identity link spans $-\infty,\infty$, it might not be appropriate. Maybe try a log link?

Comment: Following your recommendation, I did try rescaling trials, and the model successfully converged. Now, I'm just confused as to how to interpret the coefficients. Originally, the interpretation for trials would be: for every trial increase, their RT decreases by xx seconds, but now that trials have been scaled, what would be the correct interpretation? I used an identity link because it was recommended by the source I included in my original post. If I opt to use the log link, would it change the interpretation of RT? Thanks!

Comment: To answer your first point: The interpretation is, for a unit increase in `trial`, the scaled-RT increases by $\beta$ (or decreases...). Assuming the scaling is $\frac{y_i-\bar y}{s}$, that means your original/unscaled RT increases by a factor of $\beta\times s$ (not that the shifting by $\bar y$ cancels out if you do the algebra ($s$ is the sample standard deviation in my notation).

Comment: To answer your second point: an identity link has as its interpretation, a unit increase in the predictor, gives a constant additive increase/decrease in the response. A log link has as its interpretation, a unit increase in the predictor, gives constant *percentage* increase/decrease in the response (there are other links too, which have different interpretations). Also, the identity link can predict any real value, including negative means, which probably doesn't make sense for a RT. The log link forces the mean to be positive, which likely is more useful.

Comment: So I did rescale trials as in `glmer(RT~scale(cent_trial)+(1|subject)` then the interpretation would be every standard deviation increase in `trials`, `raw RT` increases (or decreases) by \beta. Am I understanding it right? If, on the other hand, RT is scaled, I would be essentially analyzing RT Z scores, correct? Then, every unit increase in `trial`, Scaled RT (or Z scores) increases or decreases by \beta.

Comment: Also, when RT is rescaled to Z scores within each participant, the overall distribution actually looks normal. In that case, I wouldn't even need to run glmers with an IG distribution, and would just need to run lmms. Does this sound right at all?

Comment: ugh. sorry, tired, I did not read "I did try rescaling trials" in your previous comment. Anyway. re `scale(cent_trial)` comment - yes, correct. Re "RT is scaled," comment - yes also correct. "the overall distribution actually looks normal. " - yes as well, you could just run a Gaussian :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!!